# jQuery Validation - How to create a method using two or more fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have several start and end dates in my system, in some cases I have several start and end dates in a screen. All of them are grouped in sets of two and have the same behaviour: the start date can't be greater than the end date and the difference between them can't be greater than a user-entered input.

I know that i have to create two methods, one for validating the first case and other for the second case. The problem is that I don't know how to reference the fields, for example:

```
// A custom method for validating the date range.
$.validator.addMethod("dateRange", function() {
    var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
    var endDate = $("#endDate").val();
    return isDate(startDate) && isDate(endDate) ? Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(endDate) : true;
});
```

The problem is: this way I hard-coded the input names. This would work if I had only one set of dates per screen, but when I have more than one this won't work. How do I create a method without hard-coding the IDs of the elements that I want to use so as to use it all around the system?

I've read the online documentation in http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/ but does seem to handle my problem and I think using groups wouldn't be enough to handle all elements, I probably would have to copy/paste for each set of dates.

I believe if you help me with one of the cases the second will be resolved using the same logic.

**EDIT: As requested, here's the HTML**

```
<table width="95%" id="tabela_interna">
    <thead><tr valign="middle"><th colspan="6">Relat&oacute;rio Interna&ccedil;&otilde;es Concierge</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td width="11%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialSolicitacao">Data Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
            <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialSolicitacao" class="data"/>

            </td>
            <td width="11%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalSolicitacao">Data Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
            <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalSolicitacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalSolicitacao" class="data"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td width="11%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialLiberacao">Data Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
            <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialLiberacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialLiberacao" class="data"/>

            </td>
            <td width="11%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalLiberacao">Data Libera&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
            <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalLiberacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalLiberacao" class="data"/>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td width="11%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataInicialInternacao">Data Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Inicial</label></td>
            <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicialInternacao" size="12" value="" id="dataInicialInternacao" class="data"/>
            </td>
            <td width="11%" align="left" class="td_label"><label for="dataFinalInternacao">Data Interna&ccedil;&atilde;o Final</label></td>
            <td width="25%" align="left" class="td_dados">
                <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinalInternacao" size="12" value="" id="dataFinalInternacao" class="data"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The [`equalTo()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method) passes a selector as an option. Try a similar approach.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the non-minified version of the plugin? I can't find it even in the gitHub page of it.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the corresponding endDate field given the startDate field (e.g. they might have same parent, class or rel attribute)?

Comment: It's linked from the [home page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: @SalmanA, I'll edit the question and provide the HTML. But I think it might be possible using something like `$(this).next('.td_label').next('.td_dados').children().first()` considering the given HTML and that _this_ is the element that I'll use in the validation rules.

Comment: I am not sure if your use of [the conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FConditional_Operator) returns what you want it to: `condition ? expr1 : expr2 ´ if true epxr1 else expr2` and for your code `(true,false and true,false) ? (false,true) : true`. So if Dat.Parse() fails for one or both dates it returns true.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree you may be right about parsing the Date, but that's not my main problem, I used it as an example. But thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the approach suggested by Blazemonger and created a method based on equalTo.

```
$.validator.addMethod("startDateCantBeGreaterThanEndDate", function(value, element, param) {
        var target = $(param);
        if (this.settings.onfocusout) {
            target.unbind(".validate-startDateCantBeGreaterThanEndDate").bind("blur.validate-startDateCantBeGreaterThanEndDate", function() { $(element).valid(); });
        }
        value > target.val();
    });
```

And used the method the same way equalTo does:

```
$("form").validate({
        rules: {
            "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao": { startDateCantBeGreaterThanEndDate: "#dataFinalSolicitacao" },
        },
        messages: {
            "filtro.dataInicialSolicitacao": { startDateCantBeGreaterThanEndDate: "Type your custom message." },
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do this using custom attributes, e.g.:

```
<input type="text" id="x" data-validate-date="true" data-validate-against="y" value="01/01/2000" />
<input type="text" id="y" value="1/1/2001" />
<input type="text" id="a" data-validate-date="true" data-validate-against="b" value="01/01/2000" />
<input type="text" id="b" value="4/4/2020" />
```

You can then define your validation rule something like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateRange", function() {
    var allValid = true;
    var results = [];
    var datesToValidate = $("[data-validate-date]");

    for(var i = 0; i < datesToValidate.length; i++) {
        var d = datesToValidate[i];
        var startDate = $(d).val();
        var endDateSelector = "#" + $(d).attr("data-validate-against");
        var endDate = $(endDateSelector).val();
        results[i] = isDate(startDate) && isDate(endDate) && (Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(endDate));
    }

    for(var j = 0; j < datesToValidate.length; j++) {
        if(!(results[j] == true)) {
          allValid = false;
        }
    }
    return allValid;  
});
```

I don't know if that's the best way to do it, but I think it could work for you.

Comment: Sorry about the terrible formatting. Am writing on my phone and struggling a bit!

Comment: No problem about the formatting. How do you initiate it in the rules?

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that this won't work if you have more than one pair of dates on a single page - let me do a quick edit...

Comment: There, I *think* that's better. I've also changed the return value as the @threeFour... above made a very good point

Comment: I'll try this, I would suggest to use the # symbol in the custom HTML attribute so as not to concat it.

Comment: I used the equalTo approach suggested by Blazemonger and is working just fine.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working - and that looks like a much smarter way of doing it than mine! I've tidied mine up and got it working so it can stand as an alternative method (perhaps how *not* to do it!)

Comment: I think your suggestion is as valid as mine, but mine is a little more like the way the author of the plugin does.